# Why every character I drag to timeline is disabled in the timeline?

Tags: unity

I dragged 3 different characters to the timeline window and each one asked for track so I did animation track for all of them but on each track on the left side there is a yellow triangle say "The component is disabled"

I created cinemachine virtual camera and it added the brain component to the main camera and created a timeline automatic for the virtual camera but when dragging a character to the timeline window I'm getting this yellow triangle with the message it's disabled.

[image: Timeline component id disabled]

You can see in the screenshot on the left side in the timeline window the yellow triangles with the message.

Comment: THe problem was that the Animator component on my characters are disabled unchecked, my game start when the animators are disabled. So the solution is to enable all the animators components and then later using a script to disable them when running the game and then enable them and enable the timeline when I need.

Comment: So it took me time to figure out what the message is referring to. it could be easier to solve it and understand it if unity was extending the message and explain a it more abou it.

Comment: :) Do you feel confident enough about that to provide it as an answer that you can then self-accept?